# PHPmailer, if mail script is visited directly an empty email sends from root

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have an email form with an action of mail.php. If mail.php is visited directly it send an email with blank information. I only want this script to execute if it is referred to by the contact page.

index.html has the contact form. Action is set to /assets/php/mail.php.

Nginx denies access to the directory and mail.php is chmod 500.

What is the best way to resolve this? If post data nulled exit? Something along those lines?

Comment: Does mail.php have to be part of web space? Can you define a php variable on index.html or does that file have to stay untouched?

Comment: So check whether it's a real submission or not, then redirect, reject or ignore the request.